# "while" loop questions for Java

Tags: java, while-loop

What I am trying to do is get a pass word from a user then check it for 4 conditions. If it's right. Then just print out "pass word is correct". If it's not, show the user what's wrong and  go back to the menu. The problem is I can not go back to the menu. IF I do a while loop in line `//User interface
        //suppose to put a while loop here, but.....
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please create a password and a legal one"`. It does go back but some of the 'if' statements do not run. Could anyone see where I am stuck in? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Text_processing
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);        //user input        
        String user_input;      // To hold input
        char[] array;           //Array for user_input
        int letters = 0;        // Number of letters
        int digits = 0;         // Number of digits
        boolean nu = true;      //
        boolean nl = true;
        boolean nd = true;
        boolean n7 = true;


        //User interface
        //suppose to put a while loop here, but.....
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please create a password and a legal one" 
                           + " should contain the following elements:");
        System.out.println("\tAt least 7 characters in length.");
        System.out.println("\tAt least 1 upper case letter.");
        System.out.println("\tAt least 1 lower case letter.");
        System.out.println("\tAt least 1 number.");

        //Get a string from the user
        user_input = kb.nextLine();

        //Convert it to a char array
        array = user_input.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(!nu && !nl && !nd && !n7)
            {               
                break;
            }

            if (array.length >= 7)       //not < 7 cos breaks
            {         
                n7 = false;        
            }

            if(Character.isUpperCase(array[i]))
            {
                nu = false;             
            }

            if (Character.isLowerCase(array[i])) 
            {
                nl = false;
            }

            if (Character.isDigit(array[i])) 
            {
                nd = false;       
            }

        }

        if(n7)
        {
            System.out.println("Password does not contain 7 or more letters.");
        }
        if(nu)
        {
            System.out.println("Password does not contain an upper case letter.");
        }
        if(nl)
        {
            System.out.println("Password does not contain an lower case letter.");
        }
        if(nd)
        {
            System.out.println("Password does not contain a number.");
        }

            System.out.println("Password is correct.");


    }
}
```

Comment: Initializing the booleans to false and doing `while (!n7 || !nu || !nl || !nd)` didn't work? What was the while-loop you tried?

Comment: Consider that if you loop back variables such as "nu" are left where they were in the previous loop.  Either "reset" them inside the loop or move the start of the loop outside where they are initialized.

Comment: You have to reinitialize `n7`, `nu`, `nl` and `nd`.

Comment: oh, thank you. I am new here and I really do not know how to edit it properly.

Comment: I did use while (!n7 || !nu || !nl || !nd) but if the password is not right. The 'if's will not run.

Comment: but how to reset them? I am new for programming so maybe a little more hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, you would need to make sure `nu`, `nl`, `nd`, `n7` are reset on each iteration of the main loop.

```
boolean badPassword = false;
do {
    boolean nu = true;
    boolean nl = true;
    boolean nd = true;
    boolean n7 = true;
    /*
     * Add everything from your code that appears below `boolean n7 = true;`
     * and above System.out.println("Password is correct."); here...
     */

    badPassword = (n7 || nu || nl || nd);
} while (badPassword);
System.out.println("Password is correct.");
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am supposed to list why the password is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, so put everything in your code that appears below `boolean n7 = true;` and above `System.out.println("Password is correct.");` within the loop...This will simply loop until the password is valid...

Comment: That makes a nice change ;)

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again but do you know how to close this question which is perfectly answered?

Comment: Can you see the gray tick next to each question?  Click the tick of the question that best meets your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with having the while loop start from:

```
String user_input;      // To hold input
```

and end before:

```
        System.out.println("Password is correct.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should you go for that specific reason already you have displayed the contents How the password should be.

just print  " The password does not meet the above criteria Please try again"

I think its enough

Comment: Thank you! But I am supposed to list why the password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern for this situation is:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = null;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("please enter something:");
    userInput = sc.next();
    if (<input fails some test>) {
        System.out.println("some reason");
        continue; // try again
    }
    // repeat other tests similarly
    break; // will only get to here if input was OK
}
```

The loop can't exit until valid input has been entered, after which `userInput` will hold that value.

Note also how by putting the prompt inside the loop, you can avoid code duplication on invalid input.

Comment: oh....there's new expression like <input fails some test> I don't know what does that mean.....Thank you anyway. I will try to find its meaning

Comment: It's just a placeholder for real code. Put whatever code there you need to test whatever you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple method to verify the password like this.

```
private static boolean isValid(char[] array) {
    if(array.length<7){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        boolean isUpper=false, isLower=false, isDigit=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            char c = array[i];
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                isUpper=true;
            }
            if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
                isLower=true;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                isDigit=true;
            }
        }
        return isUpper && isLower && isDigit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that the code you have written is too long for such a simple check.

But still the problem is hand can be fixed only if you can put a while loop which checks if the valid flag is true and also reads the key board input at the end.

Something like the code below:

```
boolean valid = false;
while (!valid) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            valid = true;
            if (!nu && !nl && !nd && !n7) {
                break;
            }

            if (array.length >= 7) // not < 7 cos breaks
            {
                n7 = false;
            }

            if (Character.isUpperCase(array[i])) {
                nu = false;
            }

            if (Character.isLowerCase(array[i])) {
                nl = false;
            }

            if (Character.isDigit(array[i])) {
                nd = false;
            }

        }

        if (n7) {
            valid = false;
            System.out
                    .println("Password does not contain 7 or more letters.");
        }
        if (nu) {
            valid = false;
            System.out
                    .println("Password does not contain an upper case letter.");
        }
        if (nl) {
            valid = false;
            System.out
                    .println("Password does not contain an lower case letter.");
        }
        if (nd) {
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("Password does not contain a number.");
        }
        if (!valid) {
            user_input = kb.nextLine();
            array = user_input.toCharArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it. I do think it's too complicated. But I am just a beginner and I am trying to simplify my logic. Thank you for the answer though. Really appreciate you do it with my messy logic.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then even have a loop you could just check the whole string using [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29). This will significantly simplify your logic

Like so

```
//For uppercase
user_input.matches(".*[A-Z].*"); // true if contians

//For lowercase
user_input.matches(".*[a-z].*"); // true if contians

//For digit
user_input.matches(".*\\d.*");  // true if contians
```